# Creación de iframe fallida (youtube) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo este iframe creado dinámicamente con jQuery pero me da el siguiente error, por lo que no puedo mostrar el video:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWIjQgwM6v0 does not permit
>   cross-origin framing.

Os dejo el código que tengo.

JS:

```
    var $frameVideo = $("<iframe allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    var atributos = {
      "frameborder":0,
      "src":planetaInfo.video
    };
    $frameVideo.attr(atributos);
    $(document.body).append($frameVideo);
```

CSS:

```
#frameVideo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 920px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar la `URL` preparada para embeber videos, es decir:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ID-VIDEO]
```

Done `[ID-VIDEO]` es `dWIjQgwM6v0`.

Adicionalmente para que los estilos se apliquen debes indicar el `id` al `iframe`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
var $frameVideo = $("<iframe allowfullscreen></iframe>");
var atributos = {
  // AQUI agregamos el ID para que tome los estilos
  id: 'frameVideo',
  frameborder: 0,
  // AQUI usamos la URL correcta
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWIjQgwM6v0'
};
$frameVideo.attr(atributos);
$(document.body).append($frameVideo);
```

.

```
#frameVideo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 920px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Antes lo había intentado con la url pero no había puesto https al principio, y el id olvide por completo asignarle, ahora funciona correctamente! @Marcos

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes cambiar es la URL del video

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWIjQgwM6v0
```

Con la palabra `watch` es un enlace directo y no sirve para el `<iframe>`. Al presionar el boton "Compartir" del video en youtube y poner el boton "Insertar" sale un `<iframe>`

Presionando este boton, puedes incluso decir desde que minuto empezar y tendras algo asi:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWIjQgwM6v0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Respecto al `style` te recomienda usar una clase y no una Id, me imagino que puedes agregar uno o más videos, si se generan dinamicamente y esto es solo una acotación.

```
var $frameVideo = $("<iframe class='frameVideo' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

Css

```
.frameVideo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 920px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Al igual que a nuestro compañero Marcos, muchas gracias! ahora funciona a la perfección, había olvidado el id y el https en la url. @sioesi